# Excel VBA Error

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

I am trying to use VBA to automatically change the color of cells that contain the piping character "|".

When detected, I would like the code to remove the piping character "|" and change the cell color to gray.  The code is not working and is listed below:

```
    With Sheets("DATASHEET").Range("AG1:BG53")
    Set c = .Find("|", LookIn:=xlValues)
      If Not c Is Nothing Then
          firstAddress = c.Address
          Do
          c.Value = ""
          c.Pattern = xlSolid
          c.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          c.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
          c.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
          c.PatternTintAndShade = 0
          Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
    End With
```

When I run the VBA, I get the following error:

*Run-time error '91':*
*Object variable or With block variable not set*

The code fails here:

*Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress*

After the crash, my Debug Watches have the following values:

*Expression `firstAddress" = $AG$37` (which is the first cell in the range that is merged and centered - a requirement)*

*Expression c.Address = Object variable or With block variable not set*

*Expression c.Value = Object variable or With block variable not set*

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

jmseiver

Update:

This code works, thanks Darren!

```
With Sheets("DATASHEET").Range("AG1:BG53")
            Set c = .Find("|", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Do
                c.Value = ""
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing
            End If
        End With
```

This code does not:

```
With Sheets("DATASHEET").Range("AG1:BG53")
            Set c = .Find("|", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Do
                c.Value = ""
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing
            End If
        End With
```

Changing the cell color is the purpose of the routine.  The additional With - End With does not work.

It doesn't bomb, it just doesn't change the cell color.

?

Thanks to everyone for their time so far!

jmseiver

Update 2:

This code works!

```
'color any cell with updated data to gray
        With Sheets("DATASHEET").Range("AG1:BG53")
            Set c = .Find("|", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Do
                c.Replace What:="|", Replacement:=""
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing
            End If
        End With
```

In summary, the purpose of this code is 1) find all cells whose first character is the piping character "|", 2) remove the piping character "|", and 3) color the cell gray.

Thanks again Darren and John!

jmseiver

Answer (score 1):

You have to test if `c` is nothing in a condition that doesn't simultaneously (albeit implicitly) assume that it isn't nothing. Something like this (untested):

```
With Sheets("DATASHEET").Range("AG1:BG53")
    Set c = .Find("|", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
       firstAddress = c.Address
       Do
          c.Value = ""
          Set c = .FindNext(c)
          If c is Nothing Then Exit Do
       Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
     End If
End With
```

The problem is that VBA, unlike most programming languages, doesn't short-circuit logical operators. Both `A` And `B` are *always* evaluated in `A and B`, even if `A` is False. As a consequence, you sometimes need to write code in a more round-about way in VBA.

Comment: You could use the original code and remove the code that deals with `firstAddress`.  The code will just loop until c is nothing once all `|` have been replaced.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Good point. I honestly didn't pay too much attention to the what the code was trying to do, but  focused instead on the particular bug that they ran into. Perhaps you could post an answer which shows how the code can be streamlined.

Comment: All, see second question update.  This ode works.  Thanks very much to Darren and John!

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified with the [Excel Find and Replace Format](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/09/29/using-excel-find-replace/#change-chell-formatting):

```
Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear                      ' optional
Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 15   ' set the replacement format
[DATASHEET!AG1:BG53].Replace "|", "", LookAt:=xlPart, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

But this like your updated code will replace all cells that **contain** `|`.

To find only cells that **start with** `|`, you can replace the find condition in your code to:

```
Set c = .Find("|*", , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```